# How can I ensure only 1 MenuAnchor menu is open at any given time?

Tags: flutter, desktop-application

I am using Flutter's `MenuAnchor` to show a context menu when a user right-clicks an item.

The issue is that if the user opens a context menu, then right clicks another item - now there are 2 context menus shown at once (possibly overlapping).

Ideally I would like for any open menus from MenuAnchor widgets to close when a new one opens, so that there is only ever the 1 shown.

I had considered pulling the state of the `MenuController`s up the widget tree so they could all be closed before calling `open()` on the new one, however I would prefer a cleaner solution since there may be hundreds or thousands of such objects that will each have their own `MenuController`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is I was using the wrong widget for a context menu.

Instead use [ContextMenuController](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ContextMenuController-class.html), which automatically ensures there is only 1 open context menu, and also provides a static method `ContextMenuController.removeAny()` to close all any open context menus.